# DataGrid SelectionChanged happens too often

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

As I have a DataGrid as another DataGrid's RowDetailsTemplate, I've got a strage effekt. If I Change selection in my inner DataGrid, the SelectionChanged-Method in the outer Grid is automatically caled, too. I don't know why, but I would like to know, what I can do against this.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but is it because SelectionChanged is a routed event and is just bubbling up through the outer DataGrid? If so, just be sure to check the `sender` parameter to see which DataGrid the event actually belongs to, before handling it.

Comment: If I Use the RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource I can check if it's the Grid for the right function, thx